# Compiler giving "already contains a definition for error" in custom class

Tags: c#

When creating a new custom class, I was trying to setup the properties like I would normally, this setup caused the compiler to give me errors though

```
public class Card
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string set { get; set; }
    public string set_name { get; set; }
}
```

This ends up giving me the error

> The type 'Card' already contains a definition for 'set_name'

It doesn't seem to be reserved word or anything.

I am sure it's something obvious I am missing, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the [IL](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQACfB+yAzLmrgMICGATjDoYQN4ONslnoAMuAdlQFsApria4A5kOABuXAGcpsgL6s2hDsm7ypoiYu0zcKvGsIB6Mxq0LgAfX7DdkwzeWrGxoA==) generated by the compiler.

Comment: Also, readability hint: if I was to read `set_name`, i'd assume it's a method to set the name; yet in your code it's a property. may get confusing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# properties are actually compiled to methods - so the `name` property is actually compiled as a couple of methods: `set_name(string value)` and `string get_name()`.

From the [c# language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction#properties):

> Properties are a natural extension of fields. Both are named members with associated types, and the syntax for accessing fields and properties is the same. However, unlike fields, properties do not denote storage locations. Instead, properties have accessors that specify the statements to be executed when their values are read or written.
>   ....
>   A get accessor corresponds to a parameterless method with a return value of the property type. Except as the target of an assignment, when a property is referenced in an expression, the get accessor of the property is invoked to compute the value of the property.
>
> A set accessor corresponds to a method with a single parameter named value and no return type.

Also, you should probably follow [naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions):

> **X DO NOT** use underscores, hyphens, or any other nonalphanumeric characters.
>   **X AVOID** using identifiers that conflict with keywords of widely used programming languages.